# PXImport in SO302000 / Split

Tags: acumatica

I would like use the Excel Upload in the screen

[image]

[image]

I have the error The code below : *Attribute 'PXImport' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations.*

```
  public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
  
   [PXImport(typeof(SOShipLine))]
   [PXViewName(Messages.SOShipLineSplit)]
```

Comment: did you redeclare the split view ?

Comment: I forgot lol ! Thanks Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [PXImport(typeof(SOShipLine))]
public PXSelect<POReceiptLineSplit, Where<POReceiptLineSplit.receiptType, Equal<Current<POReceiptLine.receiptType>>,And<POReceiptLineSplit.receiptNbr, Equal<Current<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr>>,And<POReceiptLineSplit.lineNbr, Equal<Current<POReceiptLine.lineNbr>>,And<Where<POLineType.Goods.Contains<POReceiptLine.lineType.FromCurrent>>>>>>> splits;
```

[image]